# Screw machine strips and normal square post terminals

Tags: pcb

I find in PCB design, besides the normal square post terminals like [this](https://www.samtec.com/connectors/standard-board-to-board/0100-inch-square-post):

[image]

there are another [similar one](https://www.samtec.com/connectors/standard-board-to-board/screw-machine):

[image]

Why the later called "screw machine" strips? And if it is used more in certain fileds, in comparison to square post terminals?

Comment: It's "screw machined". They are made in a machine that's similar to one which does screws. They are more exactly cut and in result, they mate within a lower profile.

Comment: @Janka: So "screw machine" only means the way they are made?

Comment: Yes. And it's still "screw machine**d**"

Comment: @Janka, you may answer the question, so that I can accept it :).